# Как можно узнать высоту страницы в пикселях?

Tags: html, php

Есть страница сайта. Можно ли как-то узнать, какова её высота в пикселях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
 var pageWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; //Ширина страницы (документа)
 var pageHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; //Высота страницы (документа)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>  
    width=screen.width; // ширина  
    height=screen.height; // высота  
    alert ("Разрешение экрана: "+width+"x"+height);   
</script>
```

Comment: в смысле? в переменной height будет твоя высота, что еще надо?

Comment: Я просил не разрешение экрана, а высоту страницы.

Comment: Можно линейкой помеять

Comment: Что за линейка?

Comment: Канцелярская.... Чем тебе предложеный вариант не подходит? Там же есть высота

Comment: Нахрен мне высота рабочей области, тоесть разрешения экрана? Если мне нужна высота страницы. Она может быть длиннее высоты монитора. Или ты не вкурсах?

Comment: Кто плюсует ответ @johniek_comp он же дал не верный ответ?!

Comment: это ТС задал не верный вопрос

Comment: блин, ТС ты что не мог в гугле посмотреть !!!

Comment: @johniek_comp, вообще то @Pavlik290592 задал правильный вопрос:

>Есть ***страница*** сайта. Можно ли как-то узнать, какова ***её высота*** в пикселях?

А вы дали не верный ответ:

   screen //Это обьект экрана а не страницы

Comment: да я хз, я js не знаю, основы только, но jquery знаю хорошо :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.documentElement.scrollHeight` - высота всей страницы

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
   $("body").outerHeight(true);
   // true что бы с отступами считало иначе false  
</script>
```

Comment: давайте по возможности более развёрнутые ответы. Автор указал в метках php: поясните что на стороне php это сделать невозможно. Уточните: а может ему в действительности они необходимы на стороне сервера? Тогда расскажите как эти данные туда доставить и по возможности как принять. Опять же...про jQuery ничего не было в вопросе. Вы должны упомянуть, что данный ответ предполагает его подключение и опять же по возможности указать способ на чистом JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, самым верным вариантом будет такой. Через js.

- document - обращаемся к текущей странице
- documentElement - наш всеобъемлющий тег , можно было бы обратиться к body, но есть риск схлопывания, что отступы вложенных в него элементов сместят и его, подробнее об этом можно загуглить)

.getBoundingClientRect() - метод, который дает информацию о положении и размерах элемента на странице.

```js
document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height
```