# Расстояние от начала документа до начала окна браузера

Tags: javascript, dom

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким методом можно узнать расстояние от начала документа до начала окна браузера?

Пример, подобную инфу можно получить при использовании document.documentElement.scrollTop
Но! если размахом листнуть вверх до начала документа, страница браузера чуть оттянется вниз и вернётся на место, что внесёт ненужные корректировки в скролл (когда страница будет возвращаться, этот процесс будет засчитан как скролл и приплюсуется).

Нужен метод, который даст эти данные игнорируя поведение браузера с оттягиванием страницы в окне браузера.
Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как можно узнать высоту страницы в пикселях?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/127445/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%85)

Comment: @Listopad02 что-то я не вижу там расстояние от начала документа до начала окна браузера